# Split list at element

Tags: list, prolog

I want to be able to split a list in two at a certain element. For example, `split_at(c, [a,b,c,d,e], Left, Right)` should give me `Left = [a,b]` and `Right = [c,d,e]`. At the moment, my code just gives me nothing at the end, even though I see `Left` and `Right` being built in the trace. Can someone please point out the mistake(s)?

```
split_at(_, [], [], []).
split_at(Element, [Element|T], _, [Element|T]). 
split_at(Element,[H|T],  Left, _) :- split_at(Element, T, [H|Left], _).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
split_at(Elem,List,Left,Right) :-
  append(Left,[Elem|Rest],List), Right = [Elem|Rest].
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean split on the first occurrence of the specified element (and not on the 3rd item in the list) :

```
split_left_right_list(Split,[],[Split|Rest],[Split|Rest]).
split_left_right_list(S,LR,R,[First|Rest]):-
    dif(First,S),
    split_left_right_list_ac(S,L,R,Rest,[First]),
    reverse(L,LR).

split_left_right_list_ac(_,AC,[],[],AC).
split_left_right_list_ac(S,AC,[S|Rest],[S|Rest],AC).
split_left_right_list_ac(S,L,R,[Not|Rest],AC):-
    dif(Not,S),
    split_left_right_list_ac(S,L,R,Rest,[Not|AC]).
```

Comment: You assumed right, I edited the question for clarity. Can you explain your solution? I'm still a beginner so I have a hard time understanding new code at first glance. For example, what is the purpose of  `dif` and `split_left_right_list_ac`?