# How can i get a sublist of list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Let's assume that I have a

list = [1,2,3,4,5]
and an element = 3

I want to get a sublist based on that element , like that
sublist = [3,4,5]

What is the implementation in Prolog ?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split list at element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49971144/split-list-at-element)

Comment: I tried :  getsublist(X,List,Sublist) :- List[X|_].

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `append/3`. This will give you the list starting from `X`. Backtracking will try to find the next `X`:

```
list_from_element(X,Ys,[X|Xs]) :- append(_, [X|Xs], Ys) .
```

To roll your own isn't much more difficult:

```
list_from_element( X, [X|Xs] , [X|Xs] ) .  % once we find X, we're done
list_from_element( X, [Y|Ys] ,    Xs  ) :- % otherwise, discard the head of the list
  list_from_element(X,Ys,Xs).              % - and recurse down
```

Again, backtracking will try to find alternate solutions by looking for another `X`